# Первый символ в отправляемом тексте через Socket

Tags: python, кодировка, сокет

Я отправляю через socket данные и клиент получая их, по первому байту, должен понять, как обрабатывать этот текст.

Отправляю тектст через socket на другой компьютер

```
 data = 0x08 + 'some text to another node'
 msg = str(data)
 s_get.sendall(msg.encode())
 data = s_get.recv(1024)
 s_get.close()
```

Получаю через socket на другом компьютере

```
data = c.recv(1024)
if not data:
  # Клиент отключился
  break
else:
  if data[0] == 0x08:
     print('Some do')
```

if data[0] == 0x08 - тут проверка не проходит, как ее провести?

Comment: Отредактируйте свой вопрос и добавьте в него полный текст ошибки.

Comment: Откуда конкретно взялся `get_msg` и почему вы решили, что к нему применим `encode()`? Нужно больше подробностей, ну и текст ошибки тоже

Comment: @sergey-gornostaev Я поправил вопрос. спасибо

Comment: @andreymal, поправил вопрос

Comment: Как-то по-моему стало хуже, ибо ответ на вопрос в текущей формулировке — `первый_байт = sock.recv(1); print(первый_байт)`; но что-то я подозреваю, что он никак вам не поможет

Comment: @andreymal, поправил еще раз :)

Comment: У вас первая строка в коде гарантированно нерабочая, так что ответить по делу мне опять нечего

Comment: сперва исправьте ошибку из-за: `0x08 + '...'` (обратите внимание: int, bytes, str/unicode это разные типы в Питоне)